# Does Android things Stable release 1.0.0 officially supports Internet using usb stick via GSM/3g/4g for Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I want to provide IOT solutions using android things in remote areas where ethernet or wifi is not available , hence, does android things stable release 1.0 supports internet via usb dongle using sim like 3g/4g in raspberry pi 3 model B

Comment: some serial downvoter got interest in my SO profile.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Unsupported Features](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0-changes#features) list `android.hardware.telephony` is not supported. But you can connect 3G/4G modules via UART and use Internet data exchange via it's AT-commands (e.g. like described in [this](http://www.microchip.ua/simcom/WCDMA/APPNOTES/SIMCom_3G_TCPIP_Application%20Note_V3.70.pdf) manual for SIMCom modules).

Comment: Ok,I will give it a try and will let you know.Thanks!